# Is there an easy way to see that $E(X^2) \geq E^2(X)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, inequality

I'm trying to memorize the Steiner translation theorem/König–Huygens formula.
The English name seems to be ["Algebraic formula for the variance"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_formula_for_the_variance#Proof)

$$Var(X) = E[(X-E(X))^2] = E(X^2) -E^2(X)\;\;\;[1]$$

I assume that since $Var(X) \geq 0$, $E(X^2) \geq E^2(X)$ holds. Correct?

There is a not too complicated proof for [1] on the wikipedia page linked that I understand. But it takes some time to reproduce it. However, I can perfectly remember the outcome of $E(X^2), -, E^2(X)$ just not the order. So (since the difference has to be $\geq 0$) is there an easy way to see which of $E(X^2)$ and $E^2(X)$ is bigger?

Best shot so far from @wiskundeliefhebber:

Remembering that one is at least as big as the other.
Then with $P(X=1) = P(X=-1) = 0.5$ follows $E(X)=0$ and $E(X^2)=1$
Ergo $E^2(X) \leq E(X^2)$

footnote: $E^2(X)$ means $(E(X))^2$

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality; not what I would call "easy" but allows you to generalize further than just squaring the random variable.

Comment: As an alternative you might like a shorter proof: $E[(X-E(X))(X-E(X))] = E[(X-E(X))X]-0 = E[X^2]-E^2(X)$.The thing to remember here is that $E[X-E(X)] = 0$ and if $E[Y] = 0$ then $E[aY] = 0$ for any real number $a$

Answer (score 5):

If you need help with remembering: just take an $X$ with $E[X] = 0$, then it is clear that $E[X^2] \ge E[X]^2$

Comment: Why the downvotes? If one takes an $X$ with $E[X]=0$, it is clear that $E[X^2]$ needs to be larger than $E[X]$

Comment: The OP wants to know why this holds for an arbitrary random variable, not just one with $E(X) = 0$. Edit: Although I suppose this helps to remember which of the two quantities is bigger.

Comment: I read the question that OP was asking for help with remembering.

Comment: The real point here is that a translation can always make $E[X]$ equal to 0, but no translation can make $E[X^2]$ equal to zero.  So looking solely $E[X]=0$ is WLOG.

Comment: Prefer "at least as large as $[E(x)]^2$."  (Or the like.)

Comment: changed to mathematical notation

Comment: I was indeed hoping for something like $E(X)^2 \leq \dots \leq E(X^2)$, using properties of E but if there's no easy way this is the best solution.

Comment: My answer was for helping to quickly remember. If you find the formula $E[( X - E[X] )^2 ] = E[X^2] - E[X]^2$ easy to calculate, then it is obvious that $ E[X^2] \ge E[X]^2$ because clearly $E[( X - E[X] )^2 ] \ge 0$

Answer (score 2):

Which is greater than which? Use the expression you already have!

Remembering how expected value is defined (and/or that the expected value of a positive quantity has to be nonnegative), write

$$0 \leq \int_{X} (X-E[X]) d\mu = E[(X-E[X])^2] = E[X^2]-E[X]^2$$

to get $E[X^2]\geq E[X]^2$.

However, this doesn't solve your problem as to **remembering** which is greater or not. Well, in this case, just memorize it. It's simple. The alternative is to rederive the above. That is, write

$$E[(X-E[X])^2] = E[X^2-2 X E[X] + E[X]^2] = E[X^2] -2 E[X] E[X] + E[X]^2 = E[X^2] - E[X]^2.$$

You don't have to worry about getting the order of $(X-E[X])$ vs $(E[X]-X)$ right. After squaring, they both give you the same result.

What's an even quicker way of remembering? Well, you get an expression $A-B$ but when you look at $(a-b)^2$ you have $(a+b)^2=a^2+b^2+\mbox{stuff}$. This means that the subtraction comes from the cross term. This means that the term subtracted has to be a factor of the cross term, i.e., $2E[X E[X]] = 2 E[X] E[X] = 2 E[X]^2$. The 2 of course goes away from the algebra. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose there are only 2 values, $X\in \{x_{1},x_{2}\}$,
$\displaystyle E^{2}(X)=\frac{(x_{1}+x_{2})^2}{4}...(1)$
$\displaystyle E(X^{2})=\frac{x_{1}^{2}+x_{2}^{2}}{2}...(2)$
$\displaystyle (2)-(1)=\frac{2x_{1}^{2}+2x_{2}^{2}-x_{1}^{2}-2x_{1}x_{2}-x_{2}^{2}}{4}$
$\displaystyle =\frac{(x_{1}-x_{2})^{2}}{4}\ge0$,
hence $E(X^{2})\ge E^{2}(X)$.

Comment: I think setting $x_1 = 1$ and $x_2 = -1$ will simplify the problem a lot.

Answer (score 0):

One way to see the thing very very easily is to think of it as a special case of 
*Cauchy-Schwarz inequality*,

[image]

where Y<sub>i</sub>s are all P<sub>i</sub>s.

Then by the given *Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality*, the result follows.

Comment: But $E[X^2] \neq n\sum X_j^2 p_j^2$.

Comment: OTOH you may get it from CS inequality as $$\left(\sum x_i p_i \right)^2 \le \sum x_i^2 p_i \cdot \sum p_i$$